# How do I post a itunes store receipt json object to a wcf service

Tags: c#, ios, wcf, itunes-store

I'm having trouble receiving post data from an iOS app with WCF. When the service is consumed my DataContract object is null. I've tried with wrapped and bare requests. Wrapped requests return method not allowed, bare requests receive the object but all of the properties are null.

Operations Contract:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "SaveReceipt/{userId}/{sessionId}/{tuttiTOKEN}/{receipt}")]
    String SaveReceipt(String userId, String sessionId, String tuttiTOKEN, String receipt);
```

config:

```
    <system.serviceModel>
      <services>
        <service name="TuttiPlayer.Webservices.TuttiServices" behaviorConfiguration="TuttiServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="TuttiPlayer.Webservices.ITuttiServices" behaviorConfiguration="web"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="TuttiServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

DataContract:

```
[DataContract(Name="receipt")]
public class Receipt
{     
    [DataMember]
    public String signature { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="purchase-info")]
    public String purchaseinfo {get;set;}
    [DataMember]
    public String environment {get;set;}
    [DataMember]
    public String Sandbox { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String pod { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="signing-status")]
    public String singingstatus { get; set; }

}
```

IOS code:

```
- (void) saveReceipt:(int)uid :(int)sid :(NSData *)receiptData {
        NSString *receiptString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receiptData    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

       SBJsonWriter *jsonWriter = [[SBJsonWriter alloc] init];
       NSMutableDictionary *jsonDic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
       [jsonDic setObject:receiptString forKey:@"receipt"];

       NSString *jsonString = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:jsonDic];
       NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonString UTF8String] length:[jsonString length]];

       NSString *serviceURL = [baseServiceURL stringByAppendingString:@"SaveReceipt"];
       NSString *serviceURLAndParam = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%d/%d/%@",serviceURL, uid, sid, self.sessionToken];

       NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:serviceURLAndParam] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10.0];
       [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
       [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
       [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];
       [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

       NSURLConnection *theConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
       NSMutableDictionary *singleConnectionDic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
       [connectionDic setObject:singleConnectionDic forKey:@"SaveReceipt"];
       [singleConnectionDic setObject:theConnection forKey:@"Connection"];
       [singleConnectionDic setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:@"FailCount"];
       [singleConnectionDic setObject:serviceURLAndParam forKey:@"URL"];
       NSMutableData *theData = [NSMutableData data];
       [singleConnectionDic setObject:theData forKey:@"Data"];

       [jsonWriter release];
       [receiptString release];
     }
```